# Cannot set NIL value for NSTimer variable in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am looking for a way to assign a nil value for NSTimer() variable in swift 2. I am using it for a stop watch application.

```
var timer = NSTimer()    

@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = nil
```

I am getting the error

> "Nil cannot be assigned to type "NSTimer"

Comment: The default initializer NSTimer() does nothing. Where do you start the timer?

Comment: To the one who down voted: Why a down vote? Its a valid question, and there is no answer for how to set it to nil. This is ridiculous.

Comment: @vadian: I initialise the timer at class level and start it after my button press.  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

Answer (score 6):

You can't set it because timer is not an optional variable. In order to be able to set nil you have to do this.

```
var timer:NSTimer? = NSTimer()    

    @IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) 
    {
      if let aTimer = timer {
         aTimer.invalidate()
         timer = nil
      } else {
        //no timer to stop. Make sure you have a valid timer created
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in other answers and comments it's impossible to set a non-optional variable to `nil`. That's one of the basic concepts of Swift.

An `NSTimer` variable is supposed to be optional and the most reliable way to start and stop a timer is

```
var timer : NSTimer?

func startTimer()
{
   if timer == nil {
      timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true) 
   }
}

func stopTimer()
{
   if timer != nil {
      timer!.invalidate() 
      timer = nil
   }
}
```

It checks always the state of the timer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var timer: NSTimer? = NSTimer()

timer = nil
```

**Swift 4.x**

```
var timer:Timer? = Timer()

timer = nil
```

Comment: doesn't work. got this error after unwrapping. "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 3):

Declare your `timer` as following:

```
var timer: NSTimer? = NSTimer()
```

Comment: doesn't work. got this error after unwrapping. "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Do you force unwrap timer after setting it to nil? Calling timer! will cause this crash, if timer is nil. I have to see more code to help you.

Comment: making it optional NSTimer, forces me to force unwrap it. timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

Comment: You can read more about optionals here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html. You should avoid force unwrapping. Try writing timer? instead of timer!.